# No public key when trying to install GCloud CLI

Tags: ubuntu, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to install the GCloud CLI according to [these instructions](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install) but I am having problems. My system is Windows 10 but I am using WSL2 with Ubuntu 20.04.

I run `curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key --keyring /usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg add -` as instructed in step 2, which is fine. Then for step 3, running

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install google-cloud-cli
```

fails with the following:

```
Err:1 https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt kubernetes-xenial InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY B53DC80D13EDEF05
```

I have tried the accepted answer from [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76299027/gpg-error-public-key-is-not-available-no-pubkey-b53dc80d13edef05-during-vm-cre) to no avail.

I am not exactly sure what else to do here and could do with some help.

Comment: Have you checked this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49582490/running-apt-update-raises-gpg-error-cloud-sdk-is-not-signed)? This is a known issue and running the mentioned commands should yield you the latest key.

Comment: Yes, this does not seem to work. I receive an error `E: This command can only be used by root.`, even after trying with `sudo`. I do not know if this is an issue with using WSL2 specifically

Comment: I was being silly and not passing sudo to the piped command. It still gave me the same output that there is no public key, but after typing `gcloud` it actually seems it was there.

Comment: Are you successful in installing the gcloud CLI with that? If so, you can post your solution for the community.

Comment: @tripleee I don't understand your comment, as you can see it was already discussed

Comment: You posted an answer which mentions that the linked post solved the problem for you. The appropriate resolution then is to mark this as a duplicate.

Comment: I have now done as you asked @tripleee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested, the solution is in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49585503/16719690). In my particular case I just needed to modify the command to use sudo:

```
curl -O https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg \
    && sudo apt-key add apt-key.gpg
```

After this, the `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install google-cloud-cli` command went through and I could call `gcloud`.